# How to convert bytes to json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to convert bytes data into JSON data. I got errors in converting data.

```
a = b'orderId=570d3e38-d6486056e&orderAmount=10.00&referenceId=34344&txStatus=SUCCESS&txMsg=Transaction+Successful&txTime=2021-06-26+12%3A03%3A12&signature=njtH5Dzmg6RJ1KB'
```

I used this to convert

```
json.loads(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

and I want to get a response like

```
orderAmount = 10.00
orderId = 570d3e38-d6486056e
txStatus = SUCCESS
```

Comment: It looks like you just want to convert a _query string_ to a dictionary? Where did you get that? Normally a query string passed to Django would be accessible as a `QueryDict` which can be accessed by `request.GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you here see is a [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), you can read the querystring with:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

a = b'orderId=570d3e38-d6486056e&orderAmount=10.00&referenceId=34344&txStatus=SUCCESS&txMsg=Transaction+Successful&txTime=2021-06-26+12%3A03%3A12&signature=njtH5Dzmg6RJ1KB'

b = QueryDict(a)
```

with the given sample data, we have a [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) that looks like:

```
>>> b
<QueryDict: {'orderId': ['570d3e38-d6486056e'], 'orderAmount': ['10.00'], 'referenceId': ['34344'], 'txStatus': ['SUCCESS'], 'txMsg': ['Transaction Successful'], 'txTime': ['2021-06-26 12:03:12'], 'signature': ['njtH5Dzmg6RJ1KB']}>
```

If you subscript this, then you always get the last item, so:

```
>>> b['orderId']
'570d3e38-d6486056e'
>>> b['orderAmount']
'10.00'
>>> b['orderId']
'570d3e38-d6486056e'
>>> b['txStatus']
'SUCCESS'
```

If you work with a view, you can also find this querydict of the URL with:

```
def my_view(request):
    b = request.GET
    # …
```